# c#: how to reference the tag property of a listviewitem

Tags: c#, listview, tags

sorry for the noob question, but I added a tag property to a ListViewItem to act as a valuemember. But now how do i reference it? Im trying to recall that tag on a double click event of the listitem at runtime. I was hoping it would be something like this (stub)

```
MessageBox.Show(lsvItems.SelectedItem.Tag);
```

how do i get at this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure there is at least one item selected and then you can do

```
 MessageBox.Show(lstView.SelectedItems[0].Tag.ToString());
```

If you have a defined entity (for eg. Person instance) added to Tag then you could do

```
Person p = (Person) lstView.SelectedItems[0].Tag
```

and access the instance's properties

```
MessageBox.Show(p.Name);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming one item is selected:

```
 MessageBox.Show(listView1.SelectedItems[0].Tag.ToString());
```